# Split Into New Tables When IDs Are The Same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that splits up information based on the week id.  This is the query that creates it:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_report WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid");

$current_week_id = -1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($current_week_id != $row['WEEK_ID'])
{
echo "<tr class='no-border'><td class='no-border'><div class='task-detail-title'>Week Number: " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</div></td></tr>";         
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th width='100'>Day</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>Start</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>End</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Billable Hours</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Non Billable Hours</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$current_week_id = $row['WEEK_ID'];
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['DAY'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['START'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['END'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['NON_BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

This works, it puts the new header which identifies the week number for every new week ID.  However what I want is:  Instead of a table with multiple grouped weeks and a header above, I need them to be individual tables.

For example say we have 3 week ID's week_1, week_2 and week_3.  I would like 3 individual tables for these weeks.  I have tried multiple ways to do this but it keeps splitting the rows up.

```
</table><table>
```

I am aware that it needs to be in the while section, just unsure where.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your SQL statement you should order records with WEEK_ID. 
And also before this part of code you should delete opening table `echo "<table>"`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_report WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid ORDER BY WEEK_ID");
$current_week_id = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($current_week_id != $row['WEEK_ID'])
{
  if($current_week_id != - 1)
   {      
      echo "</table>";
   }
echo "<table>";

echo "<tr class='no-border'><td class='no-border'><div class='task-detail-title'>Week Number: " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</div></td></tr>";         
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th width='100'>Day</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>Start</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>End</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Billable Hours</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Non Billable Hours</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$current_week_id = $row['WEEK_ID'];
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['DAY'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['START'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['END'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['NON_BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
  if($current_week_id != - 1)
   {      
      echo "</table>";
   }
```

Comment: I've used this and it works a treat.  I have a question, would it be possible to add a button after each table that carried the value WEEK_ID?  If you add a button after </table> then it does go under each table apart from the last unless you add a button after the </table> at the bottom.  But I want it to have the value of the WEEK_ID from the table above assigned to the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_report WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid");

$current_week_id = -1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<table>";

if($current_week_id != $row['WEEK_ID'])
{
echo "<tr class='no-border'><td class='no-border'><div class='task-detail-title'>Week Number: " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</div></td></tr>";         
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th width='100'>Day</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>Start</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>End</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Billable Hours</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Non Billable Hours</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$current_week_id = $row['WEEK_ID'];
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['DAY'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['START'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['END'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['NON_BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<table>";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately.  It just creates new tables for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it should work

```
<?php
$current_week_id = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

if($current_week_id != $row['WEEK_ID'])
{
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr class='no-border'><td class='no-border'><div class='task-detail-title'>Week Number: " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</div></td></tr>";         
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th width='100'>Day</th>";
    echo "<th width='75'>Start</th>";
    echo "<th width='75'>End</th>";
    echo "<th width='100'>Billable Hours</th>";
    echo "<th width='100'>Non Billable Hours</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['DAY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['START'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['END'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['NON_BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    if($current_week_id != $row['WEEK_ID'])
    {
        echo "</table>";
    }

    $current_week_id = $row['WEEK_ID'];
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

How about this? There might be a few errors there but you get the hang off what to do to solve it. Not sitting on a PHP computer at the moment so I can't check the syntax 100%.

```
$weeks = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  if(isset($row['WEEK_ID'])){               
    $tmp_array = $row['WEEK_ID']);          // fetch the existing array holding rows.
    array_push($tmp_array, $row);               // Adding a row
    $weeks['$row['WEEK_ID']'] = $tmp_array;   // Putting it back in the main array.
  } else {
    $list = array();                           // Creates a new one array
    $list[] = $row;                         // Adds the row data
    $weeks['$row['WEEK_ID']'] = $list[0];    // Stores the array under week id.
}
}

foreach ($weeks as $weekID => $week_array){
  echo "<tr class='no-border'><td class='no-border'><div class='task-detail-title'>Week Number: " . $weekID . "</div></td></tr>";         
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th width='100'>Day</th>";
  echo "<th width='75'>Start</th>";
  echo "<th width='75'>End</th>";
  echo "<th width='100'>Billable Hours</th>";
  echo "<th width='100'>Non Billable Hours</th>";
  echo "</tr>";
  foreach($week_array as $data){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $data['DAY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $data['START'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $data['END'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $data['BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $data['NON_BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```